# Issues with FORTRAN 90 receiving errors (Two main PROGRAMs , Expected PARAMETER symbol in complex constant, and Syntax error in data declaration )

Tags: fortran90

My code is below, I keep getting the following error screen. I'd really appreciate any help I could get. Thank you!

---

ERROR:

Quasi1DEuler.f90:79.13:

Q  = (0, P(i)*(Sr-Sl), 0)
             1
    Error: Expected PARAMETER symbol in complex constant at (1)

```
Quasi1DEuler.f90:184.25:

DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION Flux(W1,W2) Result(FluxArray(3,1))
                     1
Error: Syntax error in data declaration at (1)
Quasi1DEuler.f90:9.20:

PROGRAM Quasi1DEuler
                1
Quasi1DEuler.f90:185.15:

 USE parameters
           2
Error: Two main PROGRAMs at (1) and (2)
```

---

**CODE:**

```
MODULE parameters
    DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER::h=.15, t1=.8, t2=3
    DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER::gamma_constant=1.4, eps=.15
    DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER:: tol=10**(-16), pi=3.14159265358979323
    DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER:: P_t=2117, T_t=531.2, R=1716
END MODULE parameters


PROGRAM Quasi1DEuler
USE parameters
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, PARAMETER::gridpoints=50, maxiter=20000
DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER:: ExitPressureRatio=.7,dx=1/gridpoints
DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER:: cv=R/(gamma_constant-1), CFL=.4
DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER:: Pexit=P_t*ExitPressureRatio
DOUBLE PRECISION:: Minf=1.2
DOUBLE PRECISION:: residue=1, S, Flux, Ms
DOUBLE PRECISION:: IsentropicTemperature, IsentropicPressure
DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(gridpoints):: X, M, P, u, c, rho
DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(3, gridpoints)::W, Res, W_temp
DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(maxiter):: iterations, residual
DOUBLE PRECISION:: T_initial,P_initial,rho_initial,c_initial
DOUBLE PRECISION:: u_initial, Energy, a, V, Sl, Sr, Fr, Fl, dt
DOUBLE PRECISION:: dt_inlet, dp_du, Lambda, Lambda_1,Lambda_2
DOUBLE PRECISION:: Lambda_3, dt_exit, Q(3),du_inlet, R1, R2, R3
DOUBLE PRECISION:: d_p, d_rho, d_u, T_exit, Energy_exit, T_inlet
INTEGER::k=1, i

!Initialization

IF (Pexit==0) THEN
    Ms=Minf
ELSE
    Ms=sqrt(2/(gamma_constant-1)*((Pexit/P_t)**(-(gamma_con&
    &stant-1)/gamma_constant)-1))
END IF  

DATA iterations /maxiter*0/
DATA residual /maxiter*0/

DO i=1,gridpoints,1
    M(i)=Ms
END DO

Minf = Ms;
T_initial = isentropicTemperature(Minf)
P_initial = isentropicPressure(Minf)
rho_initial=P_initial/(R*T_initial)
c_initial=sqrt(gamma_constant*P_initial/rho_initial)
u_initial=Minf*c_initial

DO i=1,gridpoints,1
    P(i)=P_initial
    rho(i)=rho_initial
    c(i)=c_initial
    u(i)=u_initial
END DO


Energy    = P(1)/(gamma_constant-1)+.5*rho(1)*u(1)**2

a         = sqrt(2*gamma_constant*(gamma_constant-1)/(gamma_con&
&stant+1)*cv*T_t)

DO i=1,gridpoints,1
    W(1,i)= rho(1)
    W(2,i)= rho(1)*u(1)
    W(3,i)= Energy
END DO

DO i=1,gridpoints,1
    X(i)=(i-.5)*dx
END DO

!let us begin the  loop------------------------------------------------------------
DO WHILE ((k<maxiter) .AND. (residue>tol)) !entire loop
    DO i=2,gridpoints-1,1  !scheme
        Sl = .5*(S(X(i))+S(X(i-1)))
        Sr = .5*(S(X(i))+S(X(i+1)))
        Q  = (0, P(i)*(Sr-Sl), 0)
        V  = .5*(Sr+Sl)*dx

        u(i)     = W(i,2)/W(i,1)
        dt       = CFL*dx/u(i)
        Fr       = Flux(W(i,:),W(i+1,:))
        Fl       = Flux(W(i-1,:),W(i,:))
        Res(:,i) = (Fr*Sr-Fl*Sl)-Q
        W(:,i)   = W_temp(:,i)-(dt/V)*Res(:,i)
    END DO !end scheme

    DO i=2,gridpoints-1,1  !update vectors
            P(i)   = (gamma_constant-1)*(W(3,i)-.5*W(2,i)**&
        2/W(1,i))
            rho(i) = W(1,i) 
            u(i)   = W(2,i)/rho(i)
            c(i)   = sqrt((gamma_constant*P(i)/rho(i)))
            M(i)   = u(i)/c(i)       
        END DO !end vector update

    If (Minf<1) THEN  !inlet condition
    dt_inlet = CFL*dx/(u(1)+c(1))
    dp_du    = P_t*gamma_constant/(gamma_constant-1)&
    *(1-(gamma_constant-1)/(gamma_constant+1)*u(1)**2/a**2)&
    **(1/(gamma_constant-1))*(-2*(gamma_constant-1)/&
    (gamma_constant+1)*u(1)/a**2)

    Lambda   = .5*((u(1)+u(2))-(c(2)+c(1)))*(dt_inlet/dx)

    du_inlet = -Lambda*(P(2)-P(1)-rho(1)*c(1)*(u(2)-u(1)))/&
    (dp_du-rho(1)*c(1))

    u(1)      = u(1)+du_inlet
    T_inlet   = T_t*(1-(gamma_constant-1)/(gamma_constant+1&
    )*u(1)**2/a**2)

    P(1)      = P_t*(T_inlet/T_t)**(gamma_constant/(gamma_c&
    &onstant-1))

    rho(1)    = P(1)/(R*T_inlet)
    Energy    = rho(1)*(cv*T_inlet+.5*u(1)**2)
    c(1)      = sqrt(gamma_constant*P(1)/rho(1))
    M(1)      = u(1)/c(1)
    W(1,:)    = [rho(1), rho(1)*u(1), Energy]

    END IF !end inlet condition

    !exit condition 
    dt_exit= CFL*dx/(u(gridpoints)+c(gridpoints))

    !Eigenvalues
    Lambda_1 = (u(gridpoints)+u(gridpoints-1))/2 * dt_exit/dx
    Lambda_2 = ((u(gridpoints)+u(gridpoints-1))/2 + (c(gridpoin&
    &ts)+c(gridpoints-1))/2) * dt_exit/dx

    Lambda_3 = ((u(gridpoints)+u(gridpoints-1))/2 - (c(gridpoin&
    &ts)+c(gridpoints-1))/2) * dt_exit/dx

    ! Compute Characteristic Relations  
    R1 = -Lambda_1*(rho(gridpoints)-rho(gridpoints-1) - 1/c(gri&
    &dpoints)**2*(P(gridpoints)-P(gridpoints-1)))

    R2 = -Lambda_2*(P(gridpoints)-P(gridpoints-1) + rho(gridpoi&
    &nts)*c(gridpoints)*(u(gridpoints)-u(gridpoints-1)))

    R3 = -Lambda_3*(P(gridpoints)-P(gridpoints-1) - rho(gridpoi&
    &nts)*c(gridpoints)*(u(gridpoints)-u(gridpoints-1)))

    ! Compute Exit Mach Number
    M(gridpoints) = ((u(gridpoints)+u(gridpoints-1))/2) / ((c(g&
    &ridpoints)+c(gridpoints-1))/2)

    IF (M(gridpoints)>1) THEN
    d_p=(R2+R3)/2
    ELSE
    d_p=0
    END IF

    d_rho = (R1+d_p/c(gridpoints)**2)
    d_u   = (R2-d_p)/(rho(gridpoints)*c(gridpoints))
    !end exit conditions

    !update flow
    rho(gridpoints)=rho(gridpoints)+d_rho
    u(gridpoints) = u(gridpoints) + d_u
    P(gridpoints) = P(gridpoints) + d_p
    T_exit = P(gridpoints)/(rho(gridpoints)*R)
    Energy_exit = rho(gridpoints)*(cv*T_exit+1/2*u(gridpoints)*&
    &*2)

    c(gridpoints) = sqrt(gamma_constant*P(gridpoints)/rho(gridp&
    &oints))

    M(gridpoints) = u(gridpoints)/c(gridpoints)

    W(:,gridpoints) = [ rho(gridpoints) , rho(gridpoints)*u(&
    gridpoints) , Energy_exit] 
    !end flow update

    iterations(k)=k
    residue=(W_temp(1,:)-W(1,:))
    PRINT*, residue
    residue=maxval(residue)
    residual(k)=residue



k=k+1
END DO !end loop
END PROGRAM Quasi1DEuler

DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION S(b)
USE parameters
DOUBLE PRECISION:: b
S=1-h*(sin(pi*b**t1))**t2
RETURN
END FUNCTION S

DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION Flux(W1,W2) Result(FluxArray(3,1))
USE parameters
DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(3,1)::W1, W2, F1, F2
DOUBLE PRECISION::U1,U2,Rh1,Rh2,P1,P2,E1,E2,Rh,P,u,c,Lambda
U1=W1(2,1)/W1(1,1)
U2=W2(2,1)/W2(1,1)

Rh1=W1(1,1)
Rh2=W2(1,1)

P1=(gamma_constant-1)*(W1(3,1)-.5*Rh1*U1**2)
P2=(gamma_constant-1)*(W2(3,1)-.5*Rh2*U2**2)

E1=W1(3,1)
E2=W2(3,1)

F1=(Rh1*U1,Rh1*U1**2+P1,(E1+P1)*U1)
F2=(Rh2*U2,Rh2*U2**2+P2,(E2+P2)*U2)

Rh=.5*(Rh1+Rh2)
P=.5*(P1+P2)
u=.5*(U1+U2)
c=sqrt(gamma_constant*P/Rh)

Lambda=max(u, u+c, u-c)
FluxArray=.5*(F1+F2)-.5*eps*Lambda*(W2-W1)
RETURN
END FUNCTION Flux

DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION IsentropicPressure(M)
USE parameters
DOUBLE PRECISION:: M
IsentropicPressure=P_t*(1+.5*(gamma_constant-1)*M**2)**(-gamma_&
&constant/(gamma_constant-1))
RETURN
END FUNCTION IsentropicPressure

DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION IsentropicTemperature(M)
USE parameters
DOUBLE PRECISION:: M
IsentropicTemperature=T_t*(1+.5*(gamma_constant-1)*M**2)**(-1)
RETURN
END FUNCTION IsentropicTemperature
```

Comment: I changed it, It should be readable now. Sorry for not making it easier before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement

```
Q  = (0, P(i)*(Sr-Sl), 0)
```

isn't syntactically correct.  The error message `Expected PARAMETER symbol in complex constant` suggests that your compiler is trying to parse the *rhs* as a literal complex value and failing: it has 3 components, not the 2 that a well-formed complex number would have. The declarations in your program suggest that you should be providing a 3-element vector on the *rhs*. For that you need

```
Q  = (/ 0, P(i)*(Sr-Sl), 0 /)
```

or, if your compiler is up-to-date (-ish)

```
Q  = [ 0, P(i)*(Sr-Sl), 0 ]
```

`(` and `)` are not the correct brackets for literal vectors.

I think that the next error is caused by the compiler choking on

```
DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION Flux(W1,W2) Result(FluxArray(3,1))
```

where you've tried to declare the return type of the function twice, once as `DOUBLE PRECISION` and once as `FluxArray(3,1)` (without an explicit type that I can see.  For a function returning a vector you should use the latter form, that is declare a `result` variable.  Oh, and insert `implicit none` into the function definition and declare the type of the result.